# When browser window gets resized menu items overlaping?

Tags: jquery, menu, header, overlap

First of all I want to ask if the concept is working on your browser? Secondly when I resize the browser window and make it smaller the menus in the header are overlapping! same thing when you test it on an iphone or whatever..What can be done there? fixed menu links?

http://www.mysecretathens.gr/map/

Comment: You mean that black bar on the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.header span.right_ab {
   float: right;
   background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: `.header span.right_ab{
    position:absolute;
 right:4px;
}`

I had these before so it didnt change a lot with your code. Though it got a little better. The menus dont overlap but 2 of the 3 get out of the header if browser resized!